# send new order email with cron job only

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, cron

I want to disable the default new order email sending functionality and instead I want to send this email with cron job only. How can I identify, if the new order is placed and send email ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way of doing it.
Rewrite the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail` and make it look like this:

```
public function sendNewOrderEmail() {
    if (!$this->getForceSendEmail()) {
        return $this;
    }
    //do what it does by default
    parent::sendNewOrderEmail();
}
```

This will prevent the e-mail sending from the website because `getForceSendEmail` will always return false (unless you tell it not to).

Now, when running the cron to send e-mails you will have to do somthing like this:

```
$orders = ....; //retrieve orders somehow
$foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $order->setForceSendEmail(true); //tell the order to force the e-mail
    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but I am little bit confused about this code:                                                   $orders = ....; //retrieve orders somehow
$foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $order->setForceSendEmail(true); //tell the order to force the e-mail
    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
}                                                               Should I add this code in order.php in sendneworderemail() or in my cron.php ?

Comment: @user3719788. That should go in your cron. BUt you shouldn't edit `cron.php`. Create a model that would do this and then set it as a cron.  [See here how you can create a cron](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)

Comment: <sales_order>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0,15,30,45 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>sales/order::sendNewOrderEmail</model>
                </run>
            </sales_order>                                         Is it right? Please check

Comment: That won't work. Because you need separate instances of orders to send e-mails.

Comment: can you please tell how can I do that?

Comment: That's a totally different question. Let's keep questions separate. It is also a large topic. You should ask a new question explaining how you plan to send the e-mails. Give as much details as possible. The more details you give the better the answers might be.

Answer (score 1):

Magento is send `new order mail from Mage_Sales_Model_Sales` class function `sendNewOrderEmail`

In overrive this function using Override class
make this function

```
 public function sendNewOrderEmail(){
return;
}
```

Create another `function which code is replicated function CustomsendNewOrderEmail`  from  `sendNewOrderEmail()`
Assume

Code

setCouponCode('bal');
        //$this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'coupon_code');

```
    return;
}
public function CustomsendNewOrderEmail(){
    parent::sendNewOrderEmail();
}
```

}

**Then Using cron job hit this function:**

```
$Order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$Order->CustomsendNewOrderEmail();
```

**Create a module:**

config.xml code **((app/code/local/Bh/ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod/etc/))**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <zerosubtotalpaymentmethod>
            <class>Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model</class>
            </zerosubtotalpaymentmethod>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <autosend_order>
            <schedule><cron_expr>20 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>zerosubtotalpaymentmethod/observer::myordersend</model></run>
        </autosend_order>
    </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

**Order.php ,which rewrite Order.php`**(app/code/local/Bh/ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod/Model/)`

```
<?php
class Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order{
    public function sendNewOrderEmail(){
        // $this->setCouponCode('bal');
        //$this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'coupon_code');

        return;
    }
    public function CustomsendNewOrderEmail(){
        parent::sendNewOrderEmail();
    }
}
```

Cron file `Observer.php`**(app/code/local/Bh/ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod/Model/)**

```
<?php
class Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Observer
{
    public function myordersend(){

    $Order_collection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('email_sent',array('neq'=>array(1)));
            foreach($Order_collection as $Order)
            {
                try {

                $Myorder=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($Order->getId());
                $Myorder->CustomsendNewOrderEmail();
                }catch(Exception $e){
                }
            }
    }
}
```

also create module

```
app/etc/modules/Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod.xml
```

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod>
</modules>
</config>
```

Know more about cron job and it syntax check this

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

Comment: Please tell me how can I hit the function using cron job?

Comment: are you using magento cron system??

Comment: yes I am using magento cron system

Comment: give you shortly

Comment: Why did you copy the whole content from `sendNewOrderEmail` into `CustomsendNewOrderEmail`? Surely you could just call: `return parent::sendNewOrderEmail()` within your custom method?

Comment: When I am using this module admin login and front end customer login redirecting to a blank page

Comment: k, i will check

Comment: I have solved this issue. Problem was with this function syntax public function CustomsendNewOrderEmail(){    {                                two open curly braces but will this module send email only to the new orders or all orders?

Comment: yes. it was issue , i have just finish  check

Comment: when I am running cron.php getting 504 error PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /var/www/vhosts/vps-74.205.170.217.stwvps.net/httpdocs/garo/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 296

Comment: hi  used  remove try {

                $Myorder=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($Order->getId());
                $Myorder->CustomsendNewOrderEmail();
                }catch(Exception $e){
                }

Comment: add $Order->CustomsendNewOrderEmail();  if it not works then  it should need to increase  php Maximum execution time

Comment: hi where to add this $Order->CustomsendNewOrderEmail() and from where to remove this $Myorder=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($Order->getId()); $Myorder->CustomsendNewOrderEmail(); }catch(Exception $e){ }

Comment: your issue with php time.... execution

Comment: public function myordersend(){
$Order_collection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('email_sent',array('neq'=>array(1)));
foreach($Order_collection as $Order)
{
$Order->CustomsendNewOrderEmail();
}
}